# Character moving up with animation even with "Bake into pose" checked for Root Transform Position (Y) and no apparent movement in animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

**DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM**

I have a character with a throwing animation that has a Rigidbody with "Use gravity" checked. At the moment of the throw, in the middle of the animation, **the character moves up a from the ground**.

**OBSERVATIONS ABOUT THE PROBLEM**

This upward movement **does not seem to be present** in the animation itself when viewed in Unity's animation inspector, nor is it present in Mixamo, which is where I got it from.

The character never comes down if I **DO NOT** check the option below and keeps climbing up each time the animation is played.

[image]

If I **DO** check it, then the character **STILL** goes up but **immediately comes down once the animation is finished**.

If I check "Freeze position (Y)" as below:

[image]

The problem stops but other animations such as death animations stop working as the character floats after dying.

I **don't think it's the collider** because the character stays well up off the ground after the animation ends and keeps going up more and more each time, staying far away from the ground.

The **problem persists** with "Apply root motion" unchecked in the Animator.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

Disabling all scripts, removing the animation event that was present and fiddling with all of the settings that I mentioned here, to no avail.

**QUESTIONS**

**1)** Why could this be happening? How could I find the source of this movement given that I don't see it in Unity's animation inspector/Mixamo?

**2)** Is there a better fix than creating a StateMachineBehaviour script with OnStateEnter and turning on the Y constraint there and turning it off in OnStateExit?

Comment: If you don't get help here it might be worth reporting it to Unity in case it's a bug.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! I'll do that

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you.

In my case, the problem came from the definition of the NavMesh from a Plane. For some unknown reason, Unity created the NavMesh plane with a little elevation. Finally, I changed the plane to a cube and the navmesh succeeded, so the agents move well on zero height, as expected.

After many hours reviewing the animations and the different options, the problem was in the generation of the NavMesh.

Hope this can help you.